# PHP get value from string

Tags: php

I am doing an intern atm and I faced a problem. Basically I have a string which is `CN=van der Valk\, Marco,OU=UT,OU=NL,OU=EMEA,OU=associates,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=ingrammicro,DC=com` but I only wasn't what is after the CN which will be `van der Valk` in this case. I tried it with the trim function but didn't succeed, can anybody help me?

Comment: So you simply want to parse a LDAP DN? There should be libraries for it, and even writing something on your own is not that hard. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You will require first value from comma sapreated string which is into cn right ?

Comment: I have all the information what the ldap returns and I make a value from it using a for loop and than set the value like: `$username = $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0];`. But the problem is I don't know how to trim only what is after the CN in the string what is returned

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression? `CN=([\w\s]+)` will capture it. Check out this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Do you want the whole `CN` content (which would be `van der Valk, Marco` in your case) or only some part of the `CN` (and if so, which part would that be)?

Comment: @Jiri good point. Marco is probably first name and `\,` is just to escape the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strpos.
First I find the position of `CN=` and then use that as the offset in the second strpos (to find the end of string).

```
$str = "CN=van der Valk\, Marco,OU=UT,OU=NL,OU=EMEA,OU=associates,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=ingrammicro,DC=com";
$CN = strpos($str, "CN=")+3; // +3 because CN= is three characters.
Echo substr($str, $CN, strpos($str, '\\', $CN)-3); // -3 because we need to subtract what we added above.
```

https://3v4l.org/k5H26

---

I'm actually starting to think regex may be a good tool here.
Here I capture both firstname and lastname.
Then remove the slash and explode on comma and save them in $firstname and $lastname.

```
$str = 'CN=van der Valk\, Marco,OU=UT,OU=NL,OU=EMEA,OU=associates,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=ingrammicro,DC=com';

preg_match("/CN=([\w\s\\\\,]+),/", $str, $match);

List($lastname, $firstname) = explode(',', str_replace("\\", "", $match[1]));

Echo $firstname ." " . $lastname;
```

https://3v4l.org/9RN10

Comment: Finally, a real answer

Comment: Question for 100 points: what will happen when \ is not present in the input string?

Comment: @Jiri since \ is to escape the  comma it will be there, unless there is no first name at all. I think we need to see more variations of the string to make a proper answer that is watertight.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
$val = "CN=van der Valk\, Marco,OU=UT,OU=NL,OU=EMEA,OU=associates,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=ingrammicro,DC=com";
$valSplit = explode(",", $val)[0];
$firstVal = str_replace("\\", "", $valSplit);
print($firstVal);
```

OK,  Explode splits the string into a series of arrays, based on the comma.  str_replace takes 3 parameters.  The first is what to replace, the second is what it should be replaced with, the third being the string that should be replaced.  In this case, the goal is to remove the slash.

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: OK,  Explode splits the string into a series of arrays, based on the comma.  str_replace takes 3 parameters.  The first is what to replace, the second is what it should be replaced with, the third being the string that should be replaced.  In this case, the goal is to remove the slash.

Comment: Updated Answer here

Comment: This requires the string to always have the same order

Comment: I think CN is always in the front of an AD string, then followed by the OU's (organizational units)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'CN=van der Valk\, Marco,OU=UT,OU=NL,OU=EMEA,OU=associates,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=ingrammicro,DC=com';

// find position of 1st \, as \ is a string modifier we escape it with \\
$index = strpos($str, '\\');

echo "$index <br>";
// substr('string', 'starting index', 'length: numbers of character to get')
$new_string = substr($str, 3, $index - 3);

echo $new_string; // van der Valk
```